# How to use instafeed.js to get logged in users images

Tags: javascript, php, instagram, instagram-api, instafeedjs

I'm building an application where users can click a button to show all of their Instagram images on a page, but in order to do that I need `userId` and `accessToken`. How do I get these?

NOTE: If it makes any difference: I'm not trying to get just my own images, but anyone who uses my app to log into their account.

I have this code:

```
<script>
var feed = new Instafeed ({
    get: "user",
    userId: ,
    accessToken: ""
});
feed.run();
</script>

<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

And I get a verification code by clicking on a link (note I removed `cliend_id` and `redirect_uri`):

```
    <a href="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code">Get Instagram images</a>
```

Then this returns a code like '1251251...' which I grab with GET, but after that what do I do? How do I get userId and accesToken from this?

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I figured it out:

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

$data = array(
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
    'code' => $code
);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

`$clientId`, `$clientSecret` and `$redirectUri` are taken from: https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

`$code` is the code from your url and `$result` contains the `userId` and `accessToken` if successful.

Thanks to: [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)